# terraform creating multiple dynamodb tables foo same directory

Tags: terraform

Does any one have sample code or guide me through creating multiple Dynamodb tables through Terraform

We have module which works fine for one table. I want to iterate the same for multiple tables

```
*emphasized text*provider "aws" {
  region = var.provider_region
}

resource "aws_dynamodb_table" "hbo_dynamodb_global_table" {
   name             = "${var.table_name}"
   billing_mode     = "PAY_PER_REQUEST"
   hash_key         = "mykey"
   range_key        = ""
   stream_enabled   = "true"
   stream_view_type = "NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES"


  ttl {
    enabled        = var.ttl_enabled
    attribute_name = var.ttl_attribute_name
  }

  point_in_time_recovery {
    enabled = var.point_in_time_recovery_enabled
  }

  dynamic "attribute" {
    for_each = var.attributes
    content {
      name = attribute.value.name
      type = attribute.value.type
    }
  }

  dynamic "local_secondary_index" {
    for_each = var.local_secondary_indexes
    content {
      name               = local_secondary_index.value.name
      range_key          = local_secondary_index.value.range_key
      projection_type    = local_secondary_index.value.projection_type
      non_key_attributes = []
    }
  }
```

We have directory structure based on service. If a service has single
table this works fine . but few services we have two tables so from
the same directory ex: service/snp we want to create the two tables.

I'm trying to add count block like below please share any ideas how
the attributes can be handled

```
 resource "aws_dynamodb_table" "hbo_dynamodb_global_table" {
   count       =    var.table_count
   name             = "${var.table_names[count.index]}"
```

Comment: Please can you edit your question to show a full example of what you've tried and also show what problems you've encountered? If it errors in some way then it's useful to include the full error output. If it doesn't do what you want it's useful to explain what it's doing from your included code and then explain how that's different from your intended goal.